# How to fix broken package dependency with apt on Debian

Tags: debian, terminal, apt, package-management

I plan to move my VM to my VPS providerju, but I need Python module that is required by the mover app ( snf image creator). However it won't let me install curl. Then error says that curl and two additional libs are required as  dependencies, but I have also broken packages. I tried to apply my apt-get knowledge (apt clean, autoremove,...), but it does not do the Job.
**Updated image. Cannot / Don't know to copy text from VM ware player**

[image: Description od the error]

[image: I messed up my sources.list file while entering another repo]

Comment: Welcome to U&L , Please post a text instead of an image , to translate from you locale language to Eng you can use (e,g) :`LC_ALL=en_US your_command` , Also the content of your  `/etc/apt/sources.list` may be helpful , [You can edit here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/435910/edit)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I took the photo before I went home from my dormitory. Sure i'll post this in english when get home.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: Can you tell me how how to copy from VM vare workstation 14? I enabled all I could.

Comment: `libcurl3 (7.52.1-5+deb9u5)` is a security update and your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should contain the security repo to apply this update. Edit your sources.list as the [officiel docs say](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list) (the second example) then run `apt update && apt upgrade`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It worked and packages are installing. I had proprably erased the whole sources.list file with echo "okeanost_repository_site" >> ..sources.list

Comment: Screenshots are evil. Use text copy-paste. I vote for "leave close" now that.

Comment: Why my answer gets down vote? I gave answer before S4NNY1 edited the question. As per the updated question, I also updated my answer. Then still it is down vote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Example sources.list from [Debian website](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)
Below is an example of a sources.list for Debian 9/Stretch.

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
```

If you also want the contrib and non-free components, add contrib non-free after main:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

You can use a GNOME tool to edit your  sources.list file. Access it through Menu → System → Administration → Software Sources.

```
gksu --desktop /usr/share/applications/software-properties.desktop /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk
```

Comment: I'll try the delete option. My package manager is apt and not apt-get.

Comment: The problem come from the `sources.list`, please see the update.

Comment: I added `sourced.list` in solution 0

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the answer button. Or, If you would have solved by yourself, please share the solution.

Comment: Just keep the first part of the answer. The 3 last solution will not help.

Comment: I updated my answer as per your requirements.